# DNS no longer working after Ubuntu-Desktop installed

Tags: server, 18.04, dns, netplan, systemd-resolved

I built a Ubuntu Server 18.04 server to play with Docker and a few other things. When I initially installed Server I had some issues with Netplan and getting DNS (my own server) to work, but I go there in the end and all was working fine.

There were a few other things I wanted to do, that I felt required me to have a GUI installed, so I installed Ubuntu-Desktop using `apt install --no-install-recommends 
 Ubuntu-Desktop`. After a reboot, there was the GUI and I was able to login. Great!

However, I no longer have DNS working again, and I didn't record what I did first time to sort it!. If I do an nslookup of a local host I get: `;; reply from unexpected source: 127.0.0.1#53, expected 127.0.0.53#53`

As always my first response is to Google for assistance, but I don't relly understand the various suggestions so don't want to wildly start typing commands in the terminal.

All I have done thus far is to confirm my netplan config is still there and reapplied it. I also installed resolvconf which was one of the suggestions. If I open `/etc/resolv.conf` I see `Generated by NetworkManager`. I am more familiar with CentOS and have no experience of Netplan other than what I did earlier when I first installed.

Any advice and explanation would be appreciated....

**UPDATE 1:** I'm wondering if this has anything to do with Docker being installed on this system??

**UPDATE 2:** As requested, here are the outputs of those commands:

```
$ dpkg -l *dnsmasq*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-============================================================
un  dnsmasq                     <none>             <none>             (no description available)
ii  dnsmasq-base                2.79-1             amd64              Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
un  dnsmasq-base-lua            <none>             <none>             (no description available)


$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May  8 16:06 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf


$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search home.domain

$cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses: [192.168.1.6/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.3
        search:
          - home.domain

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown

auto eth0
iface etho inet static
        address 192.168.1.6
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        netowrk 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.3
        dns-domain home.domain
        dns-search home.domain
```

**UPDATE 3:** Heynnema tried to help me. We corrected the /etc/network/interfaces file as per his comments, and uninstalled dnsmasq-base which we believe was left over from a removed Pi-hole install. Now nslookup returns a failure trying 127.0.0.1.

**UPDATE 4:** Output of `ps auxw |grep systemd`

```
root       474  0.0  0.2 118876 33216 ?        S<s  May08   0:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       519  0.0  0.0  47160  5784 ?        Ss   May08   0:02 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
systemd+   747  0.0  0.0 141924  3348 ?        Ssl  May08   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
systemd+   881  0.0  0.0  71968  5996 ?        Ss   May08   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
root       987  0.0  0.0  70604  6192 ?        Ss   May08   0:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
message+  1041  0.0  0.0  51620  6140 ?        Ss   May08   0:04 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
gdm       1789  0.0  0.0  76984  7948 ?        Ss   May08   0:07 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
neild+  8004  0.0  0.0  77024  7928 ?        Ss   May08   0:07 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
neild+ 26628  0.0  0.0  13136  1072 pts/0    S+   19:37   0:00 grep --color=auto systemd
```

**UPDATE 5:** I managed to get systemd-resolved working again and thus /etc/resolv.conf to exist by running `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` and then `systemctl start systemd-resolved.service`

nslookup now gives `;; reply from unexpected source: 127.0.0.1#53, expected 127.0.0.53#53` again

**UPDATE 6:** Found the issue, but no idea why it only started being an issue. So I have Docker running with a Pi-Hole container (I hear you all grown!) which is using port 53 and preventing systemd from working correctly. The docker-proxy process had the port instead.

When I stop the docker service and restart systemd-resolve all works as expected, so I have temporarily removed my Pi-Hole container.

Is there a way to get both working together?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *dnsmasq*` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @heynnema Please see Update 2 above

Comment: I see two potential problems... 1) your symlink for /etc/resolv.conf is **probably** incorrect... more on that later. 2) you've defined your network in **both** /etc/netplan/*.yaml **and** /etc/network/interfaces. You're combining netplan and NetworkManager definitions at the same time. Since you're on a server, you should be using netplan. Edit your interfaces file to only contain `auto lo` and `iface lo inet loopback`. (and network is spelled incorrectly).

Comment: dnsmasq-base may also be a problem. Do you need that for any particular reason? More on that later.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks, no idea how that content got added to interfaces file if not there by default as I certainly didn't dd it. I've edited the file and am rebooting now.

Comment: @heynnema DNS still not working. nslookup shows no response from 127.0.0.1 which is expected since there is not DNS server on here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93407/discussion-between-neildeadman-and-heynnema).

Comment: @heynnema Thanks again for trying!

Comment: very welcome. sorry I didn't fix it.

Comment: The resolv.conf link looks normal (stub...) and the contents are normal for systemd.  What does the systemd-resolve --status output look like (get second page too).  I suppose if DNS is left at your gateway, you could change it in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.

Comment: @ubfan1 it returns `Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

Comment: Does a ps auxw |grep systemd  show a systemd-resolved running?  Does /var/log/bootstrap.log have the creation of the symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service ? Some service seems not to be running.

Comment: @ubfan1 no to systemd-resolved running (full output above in update 4) and yes the bootstrap.log has that entry `Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service -> /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.`

Comment: Removed the lts tag and added the ssytemd-resolved one (5 max).  Try a dpkg-reconfigure on systemd, or you could cut systemd out of the resolve loop entirely by redirecting the /etc/resolv.conf symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/recolv.conf instead of the stub-resolv.conf (providing you really have your nameserver in that file. Better to fix the systemd problem than to just avoid it.

Comment: @ubfan1 I ran `dpkg-reconfigure systemd` which seemed to work, but I see no change to the output of `ps aux | grep systemd` - also I seem to have no /etc/resolv.conf file anymore.

Comment: `systemd-resolve --status` gives `
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93453/discussion-between-ubfan1-and-neildeadman).

Comment: I suspect it would be easier to rebuild, and I may just have to do that, but it would be nice to know what the issue is so I can fix it